# Trying to figure out making a popup window with form in JavaScript, also cookies to remember login attempts for 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, navigation, popup

I have searched around everywhere and no answers to this have shown up.
I am trying to make a login page open up in a popup window, with a fixed size, fitting the form.
You don't need to reprimand me about keeping login info client side, it's just an experiment.
Here's my form, with JS and CSS as well, along with my home page that has a button to redirect to the login and signup pages. (The signup page isn't working yet, and I'll probably ask about how to do that too but that's another thing altogether)
The home page is nowhere near complete obviously.
I just want the page to open the login page as a window, and then people can get redirected to the success.html page with their number in it.
The success pages should also appear in the original window, not the popup.

You also don't need to tell me how awful and crude my coding is, I am new to all this.

Thanks!

(P.S.- If anyone happens to know how to use cookies to make the site remember someone's login attempts for 5 minutes even when/if they close the site that would be awsome!!)

These are my files:

LOGIN PAGE HTML:

```js
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if (username == "Formget" && password == "formget#123") {
    alert("Logged in successfully. Welcome, User 1.");
    window.location = "success1.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
    return false;
  } else if (username == "Formget2" && password == "formget#123") {
    alert("Logged in successfully. Welcome, User 2.");
    window.location = "success2.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
    return false;
  } else if (username == "Formget3" && password == "formget#123") {
    alert("Logged in successfully. Welcome, User 3.");
    window.location = "success3.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
    return false;
  } else {
    attempt--; // Decrementing by one.
    alert("You have left " + attempt + " attempt(s).");
    // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
    if (attempt == 0) {
      alert("You have run out of attempts, please try again in 5 minutes.");
      document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
h2 {
  background-color: #FEFFED;
  padding: 30px 35px;
  margin: -10px -50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

hr {
  margin: 10px -50px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

div.container {
  width: 900px;
  height: 610px;
  margin: 35px auto;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

div.main {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 50px 25px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: 'Audiowide', monospace;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label {
  color: #464646;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

center {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.note {
  color: red;
}

.valid {
  color: green;
}

.back {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 143, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 214, 255);
  padding: 3px 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: black;
}

input[type=button] {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ffbc00 5%, #ffdd7f 100%);
  border: 1px solid #e5a900;
  color: #4E4D4B;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffdd7f 5%, #ffbc00 100%);
}
```

```html
<html style="font-family: 'Audiowide', monospace;">

<head>
  <title>Log In</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" />
  <script src="login.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <h2>Log In</h2>
      <form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
        <label>User Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
        <label>Password :</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()" />
      </form>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<body onload="checkCookie()"></body>

</html>
```

HOME PAGE HTML (CSS INSIDE):

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Audiowide', monospace;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="login" target="popup" onclick="window.open('login','jbnWindow','width=600,height=400')"><b>Log In</b></a>
<a href="signup" target="popup" onclick="window.open('signup','jbnWindow','width=600,height=400')"><b>Sign In</b></a>
```

The files above are as follows, in order:
login
login.css
login.js
home

My goal was to to make the login pop up in a new window and then redirect to each user's specific success page, but instead it opens both a window and a tab with the page, not just a window. The window also is not fixed size.

I also am looking to use cookies for the login attempts, as I said, and any tips on that would also be helpful.

Comment: Only use cookies if you need to send their data to the server

Comment: I made some snippets for formatting's sake. SO does not support cookies. But do look at [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: How would I make the attempts be saved when they leave and come back? Right now, they can easily circumvent the 3 attempts by simply reloading the page.

Comment: Use JS LocalStorage to store last login date or number of attempts. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Do you know how someone completely new to localstorage (and a js newb) could do that?